# angular2 array push in object from database

Tags: arrays, mongodb, angular, typescript, vaadin

im using angular2 rc5

im creating an array caled user and then push in data from mongodb which is just id from mongodb and an email user

```
(1)    public user[] = [];
    for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                this.user.push(data[i]);
                }
```

and the result that i got is like this

```
->[]
Object
_id:"57bbd5f8f6f5382c313f1cfe"
email:"rommy.gautanto@map.co.id"
__proto__:Object

1:Object
_id:"57c4f5210e7f0d181a0ec9f8"
email:"zxcv"
__proto__:Object

2:Object
_id:"57c64ed4918f02f80a269121"
email:"asdf@map.co.id"
__proto__:Object

length: 3
```

the second try is like this

```
(2) public user[] = [
{email:'asdf'}
{email:'12345'}
{email:'plaskd'}
];
```

and i got the result

```
->[object,object,object]  <<---- here is the diferance
Object
email:"asdf"
__proto__:Object

1:Object
email:"12345"
__proto__:Object

2:Object
email:"plaskd"
__proto__:Object

length: 3
```

im using the array into the vaadin combo box the 2nd sucess, but the 1st keep on error

> uncaught TypeError: (item) should be a valid item

how to make the 1st working

Comment: How are you using the array in vaadin combo box? Does it work if you change the second to have "id"?

Comment: In standard international English we capitalize the first word of sentences, capitalize the word "I", and place punctuation at the end of sentences. This is not a chatroom or an SMS conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is an issue somewhere. I managed to reproduce this and found a workaround, but the exact reason is still unknown for me. While we are investigating further, please use the following workaround.

Instead of adding the items from data source directly to the `this.user` array, collect them in a new array instance and then assign to the user property:

```js
var usersData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  usersData.push(data[i]);
}
this.user = usersData;
```

Comment: thanks its working, i guess is something wrong with the direct push to the array